# Select some string from sentence

Tags: regex, autoit

I am new to regex and would like to select some string following rule:

> Select "beautiful"(zero or one) and "people00" or "peopleXXX" if matched.

sentence:

1. "I am beautiful, charming and friendly people00"
2. "I am beautiful, charming and friendly peopleXXX"
3. "I am charming and friendly people00"
4. "I am charming and friendly peopleXXX"

Now I use below rule to get two string

```
(?i)(beautiful| ).*(people[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})
```

Is there another ways to select it?

I tried to directly use `(beautiful)?.*(people[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})` but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a greedy dot matching subpattern in the regex. This `.*` makes it impossible to capture *beautiful* as it is already matched with `.*`. The optional group `(beautiful)?` or an obligatory group `(beautiful| )` just match either nothing (#1, the group is "non-participating") or the first space (#2). To avoid that you need to restrict to match anything but *beautiful* up to *peopleXXX*.

One way is to use a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
(?i)(beautiful)?(?:(?!beautiful).)*(people[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQ6aT1/1)

The `(?:(?!beautiful).)*` will match any symbol but a newline that does not start the sequence `beautiful`.

Another way is to use an unrolled version of this tempered greedy token:

```
(?i)(beautiful)?[^b]*(?:b(?!eautiful)[^b]*)*(people[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQ6aT1/3)

The `[^b]*(?:b(?!eautiful)[^b]*)*` matches any text that is not starting the `beautiful` character sequence (it will match characters other than `b` zero or more times (`[^b]*`) then any number of sequences of `b` not followed by `eautiful` (`b(?!eautiful)`) and then followed by zero or more characters other than `b`.

Note: to make this regex a bit more efficient, you can [include a check](https://regex101.com/r/wQ6aT1/4) for `peopleXXX`:

```
(?i)(beautiful)?(?:(?!beautiful|people[a-zA-Z0-9]).)*(people[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})
```

and an [unrolled one](https://regex101.com/r/wQ6aT1/5):

```
(?i)(beautiful)?[^bp]*(?:p(?!oeple[a-zA-Z0-9])[^p*]|b(?!eautiful)[^b]*)*(people[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, this is what I need. I will search (?:) and (?!)

Comment: You should check the [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) explanation. It does consist of a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) and a negative lookahead `(?!...)`.